# The underlying provider failed on Open in WCF IIS

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

I have an app which connects fine to my WCF service in my test computer. When i deploy to IIS and run the application, i get the error message above. The WCF service pulls from SQL Server. I have tried [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/126919/Solution-for-The-underlying-provider-failed-on-Ope) but I still get the same error. Please help

Comment: That's pretty vague, you should try to give as many details as possible.

Comment: `Underlying Provider Failed on Open` is the typical error you get when your Entity Framework Connection string is wrong. Close-voting for lack of effort to research.

Comment: Hi HighCore it worked perfectly until i deployed the service to IIS, and i've done some serious research.

Comment: Enable svclog at server side by adding System.Diagnostics tag and inspect the svclog file using the SvcTraceViewer will help you to find out the exact issue